# Microsoft Graph API - thinking its JSON parse error within the Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying this:

```
 var report_SP_Usage_File_Counts =  await 
 graphClient.Reports.GetSharePointSiteUsageFileCounts("D180").Request().GetAsync();
```

and i get this error:

```
    System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'R' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
    ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'R' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
      at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
      at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
      at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
      at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
      at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
      at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
      at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter converterBase)
      at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ContinueDeserialize[TValue](ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack, JsonConverter converter, JsonSerializerOptions options)
      at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAllAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Microsoft.Graph.Serializer.DeserializeObject[T](Stream stream)
      at Microsoft.Graph.ResponseHandler.HandleResponse[T](HttpResponseMessage response)
      at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
      at MinimalAPI.Endpoints.Reporting.mw_m365_GroupActivityTable_GRAPH()
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<ExecuteTask>g__ExecuteAwaited|58_0[T](Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
      at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
      at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Trying to get the Sharepoint  Site Usage File Counts, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this as a workaround

```
var message = graphClient.Reports
              .GetSharePointSiteUsageFileCounts("D180")
              .Request()
              .GetHttpRequestMessage();
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
// Download report data
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```